# Branching in an Automated Build

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, branching-and-merging

I'm pretty new to tfs and automated builds so bear with me.

I'm trying to edit an automated build template so that a branch of my main is created every time the automated build is run.  Any idea on how to do this in a workflow using the tools provided by tfs in visual studio?

Any help or advice would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to do this, probably. Making a branch for every single build would be very expensive, and is unnecessary. You can configure TFS to make a [label](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181439(v=vs.100).aspx) each time a build happens to capture the source that went into that. You can use that label for future source control operations like diffing changes. If you need to modify that specific stuff, you can (at a later time) also make a branch from the labeled source.

[Read the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181439(v=vs.100).aspx) on the topic, it's quite possible this already addresses your need, does so in a way that's faster, and is conveniently supported without modifying the build template.

Comment: I have read said docs before and unfortunately that is not what I am required to do.  The automated build process for my project is only run on publishing and deployment so it's not like this would happen each time I built.

Comment: My goal is to have a branch of my entire project created before release so that I have a complete history of all deployments for my project.

Comment: A build maintains the chengeset number which is immutable. The changeset number allows you to create a branch if necessary at any time in the future.

Comment: Labels give you the history you want: you can easily query for the list of labels which would be the history of deployments. Having a branch isn't necessary.